# When converting path variable in a list it prints extra symbols \\

Tags: python, python-3.x, pythonpath

First in my code I created variable rootdir:

```
rootdir = r'\\001\Server\Folder1\Folder2\Folder3\Folder4' # shared drive
print(rootdir)
```

**Output:**

```
\\001\Server\Folder1\Folder2\Folder3\Folder4  # looks good
```

Then I'm creating a list of paths,  so I can attach files from that location

```
files = [rootdir +  '\\' + 'MyFile.xlsx']
print(files)
```

**Output:**

```
['\\\\001\\Server\\Folder1\\Folder2\\Folder3\\Folder4\\MyFile.xlsx'] # has extra \\
```

I need to use list of paths in a function:

```
# function sends email
def send_mail(send_from,rcpt,subject,text ,files):
    assert isinstance(send_to, list)
    assert isinstance(cc, list)
    assert isinstance(files, list) # files need to be a list
    msg = MIMEMultipart()
```

Now the path has extra `\\`

Why does it happen and how can I get rid of those `\\` to get path look like this:

```
\\001\Server\Folder1\Folder2\Folder3\Folder4\MyFile.xlsx
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's do do with how printing a list evaluates. The actual contents of the list is as you want.

```
In [9]: print(files)
['\\\\001\\Server\\Folder1\\Folder2\\Folder3\\Folder4\\MyFile.xlsx']

In [10]: for file in files:
    ...:     print(file)
    ...:
\\001\Server\Folder1\Folder2\Folder3\Folder4\MyFile.xlsx
```

Comment: variable files need to be converted to a list. Otherwise I get an AssertionError in my send_mail function. But converting it to a list gives me incorrect path address.

Comment: @Serdia no it doesn't, it's just the way the list is being represented. Those extra back-slashes are not actually in your string. You can't print it to check. Just like there are not actual brackets ([]) in your list...

Comment: Oh. Got it. Thank you guys!